# How to refresh list after workflow completes

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow

I'm using Sharepoint 2013

I need to refresh a list after a workflow completes to show the updated information. Any guidance? I need it directly tied to the completion of a workflow, not a general "refresh every 5 minutes scenario".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the page after the workflow is completed, we can use code behind to keep checking the status of workflow. Once the workflow is completed, reload the page.

You can take a look at Alexander's blog, he provides code on this requirement:

- [Check workflow status and refresh page when status equals
  “Completed”](https://spjsblog.com/2010/01/11/check-workflow-status-and-refresh-page-when-status-equals-completed/)